# Se houver hint ou warning o compilador cancela a compilação

Tags: delphi

Gostaria de que ao compilar uma aplicação e caso ela possua algum *Hint* ou *Warning*, a execução seja suspensa, gerando um erro.

Alguém sabe se é possível?

**Edit1:**
*Warning's* podem ser tratados como erros. Mas existe algo que possa fazer com que *Hint's* também sejam tratados como erros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre que clica nas teclas `Shift` + `F9` usada para fazer um *Build* do projecto, é criado uma caixa de *Messages* onde é possível visualizar os `hint` e `warning` do projecto, sempre que existirem **ERROS** o *Delphi* não deixa executar o projecto.

Exemplo com **Hint**:

[image: Hint]

Exemplo com **Warning**:

[image: Warning]

Tal como mencionou o @JúniorMoreira para editar os *Hint* e *Warning* a aparecer basta ir no *Tab* **Project** -> **Options** -> **Delphi Compiler** -> **Hints and Warnings**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode ainda fazer uma *Build* ao projecto clicando no *Tab* **Project** -> **Build Project**.

**EDIT1:**

As únicas opções disponíveis para escolher são: `TRUE` ou `FALSE` no caso dos *Outputs Hints* assim como poder ver na imagem abaixo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao contrário dos *Output Warnings* que podem ter a opção `AS ERRORS` pode verificar na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria interessante você citar que sua edição foi baseada na minha resposta!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira apesar de ter escrito isso na sua resposta nao e a unica fonte onde me asegurei de como o fazer. Contudo editei a minha resposta e espero nao ter causado grande encomudo ou arranjado uma briga. Bom fim de semana

Answer (score 3):

Sim é possível,

Acesse Project, Option, Delphi Compiler... e em Hints and Warnings você configura..

Ex. Deprected Symbol, quando existe uma variável declarada e não usada, ele gera um HINT, você pode configurar para que seja um ERRO.

Dessa forma não ocorrera a compilação da Aplicação!

Obs. Você pode configurar o Release para isso e deixar o Debug como esta. Dessa forma a Aplicação final estará garantida sem Hints e Warnings.

Comment: É possível que um Hint gere um erro?

Comment: Sim, na resposta eu mencionei `Ex. Deprected Symbol, quando existe uma variável declarada e não usada, ele gera um HINT, você pode configurar para que seja um ERRO.`

Comment: Funciona com Warning, pra Hint não há essa opção.